# PHP Tree Traversal For Sub Forums Within Sub Forums

Tags: php, mysql, database, dynamic, tree

I have been developing my own forum for about a week now and I am almost done with all of the code, however, I am stuck on one single issue that I have not been able to figure out.

Well, simply said I have sub forums that can be within any amount of other sub forums.

How would I create a path dynamically to any of those sub forums on the spot with PHP.

After the path is created I would use it within href's and other things.

I am guessing I would somehow need to traverse the database based on a ID column and another column that would link one sub forum to another sub forum.

Let's assume that my database table looks like this:

```
ID | Name        | Link |
---+-------------+-------
1  | Forum-One   | Top  |
2  | Forum-Two   | 1    |
3  | Forum-Three | 2    |
4  | Forum-Four  | 2    | 
5  | Forum-Five  | 3    |
6  | Forum-Six   | 3    |
```

How would I go about doing this - or is there something else that must be done instead?

I hope I was clear enough for everyone to understand.

EDIT:

```
 include("inc/config.php");

 function generateBreadcrumb($startingID){

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE ID='$startingID'");

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
    $db_id=$row['ID'];
    $db_name=$row['Name'];
  }

     if($db_id!='Top'){
         return generateBreadCrumb($db_id);
     } else {
         return $db_name;
     }
 }

 $startID='6';
 echo generateBreadcrumb($startID);
```

Comment: Why are you looping through your results array?  You only need to call $row=mysql_fetch_array($result) once.  Remove the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need a terminating condition.  So set your top level Forum[link] to null, or 'top', or something.  Then its simply a matter of using a recursive function put your bread-crumb together.

So lets assume you wanted to go to display the breadcrumb to Forum-One:Forum-Three:Forum-Six , better known as Forum-Six.

Example code:

```
 <?php
 $yourForumId = 6; // replace this dynamically with your forum;
 $breadcrumb = generateBreadcrumb($yourForum);
 function generateBreadcrumb($startingForumId){
     $sql= "SELECT Name ,link FROM Forums WHERE ID = ".$startingForumId;
     //run your $sql however you do to get results
     //assuming you get associative arrays back
     if($res['link'] != 'top'){
         return generateBreadCrumb($res['link']).":".$res['Name'];
     } else {
         return $res['Name'];
     }
 }
 echo $breadcrumb;
 ?>
```

It's recursion, which if you're new to it may seem complicated, but I hope that helps!

EDIT: here's your code with the needed edit...

```
include("inc/config.php");

 function generateBreadcrumb($startingID){

     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_table WHERE ID='$startingID'");

     $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
     $db_id=$row['link'];
     $db_name=$row['Name'];

     if($db_id!='Top'){
         return generateBreadCrumb($db_id).":".$db_name;
     } else {
         return $db_name;
     }
 }

 $startID='6';
 echo generateBreadcrumb($startID);
```

Comment: I see in theory of how the concept works by running the function until it detects 'top' and then stops. I also see how I could put all of the information that is returned into an array. But the array aside I cannot even display the 'top' values name using this. I believe it is stopping when the first function is returned (If I remove the 'top' condition it displays the name of the first specified forum, so the sql select is not the problem). I added my code to my question. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @Anvio There's no array other than your results array's.  you're missing the last part of the call when the link != 'top'.

Comment: Ha, that makes sense. But I still seem to not be getting any results displayed. And incase if you were going to ask I did change my DB's Forum-One link to Top.

Comment: Oh, I missed something.  You need to be looking at the link column, not the ID. updating code now.

Comment: Haha did not catch that either - it is getting a bit late. Works perfectly now, thank you very much for sticking with me through this. Hooray for learning something new!